# how do taplytics, mixpanel, optimizely or apptimize work?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, taplytics

This is a mind bender for me, guys. Does anyone know how the four services in the title (and probably many more) do the things showcased in this video?:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ_-4qM4P2U

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lv9RCdYoak4

It seems they can somehow stream the Android/iOS device's screen to the browser but also the complete view tree, along with all properties so they can accurately render the UI in HTML5. After you change something in the browser, it is instantly applied on the device itself, without any app build or update.

Any idea how that's done on Android or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a live server which you can check from [github](https://github.com/tapio/live-server).

The same thing is used in the likes [Cordova/PhoneGap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-server)

So simply put all that is done is that the server watches for any file changes then reloads the web page.

The server can either be remote or local, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering, how these portals works. While searching it on google, I came across this question on SO

[How does Apptimize \ Optimizely work on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879195/how-does-apptimize-optimizely-work-on-ios)

https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/205014107-How-Optimizely-s-SDKs-Work-SDK-Order-of-execution-experiment-activation-and-goals#execute

It helped me in getting the basic idea.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you've already coded the screen in your app using their SDK. All changes you do to the screen configuration of elements and texts are updated to their servers and then retrieved in real time by the mobile apps from their server. Each and every configurable element has to be coded using their sdk to be able to change in run time.

Comment: that's actually not the case. You just add one line of code to an existing app and it works like magic. You definitely don't have to create the UI with their SDK - I tested their services.